# Not able to update data in target table in ETL

Tags: etl, informatica

i have taken target table as my lookup table using static cache.in source i have duplicate values.

in mapping i ahve used update strategy transformation but not i m not able update data in target table

Example:Initially(i mean after session Load)

```
source table         Lookup table          Target table

ID    Name           ID    Name            ID    Name    
1     A              1     A               1     A 
2     B                                    2     B
```

Now im inserting two more records

```
3      C
1      E
```

but its not updating below record

```
1    E
```

i am getting below error

> One or more values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or foreign key update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid because the primary key, unique constraint or unique index identified by "1" constrains table "TABLE_NAME" from having duplicate values for the index key.

I know if i use dynamic lookup it will work correctly but in static.
please give the reason ASAP.

Comment: Run the mapping in debugger to identify where the issue is.

Comment: Thank you i got the mistake.one more thing does any one know knows why dynamic lookup not support unconnected lookup